# Get data from referenced table in Sequelize and Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am taking sender_user_id and order_status as input from the user and displaying all fields in the order table corresponding to the given input. Now, I want to the product id from the order table to reference to the product_id in the products table and display the information related to the product. How can I do this?

```
const db =require('../../models')
const Orders = db.orders
const Products = db.products


const orderDetails=async(req,res)=>{
    
    try {
        const order = {
            //user_id: id,
            
            sender_user_id:req.body.sender_user_id,
            order_status:req.body.order_status
         
            
        };
   
    
        

        Orders.findAll({
           where:{
               sender_user_id:req.body.sender_user_id,
               order_status:req.body.order_status

           },
        })
        .then((order) => {
          if (!order) {
            return res.status(400).send({ 
              status:"102", 
              message: "order Not found." });
          }
          res.status(200).send({
            status:"VB100",
            orders: order});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
    }catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.json({
            status:"102",
            msg: err.message
        })
    }

    };



module.exports={orderDetails};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const db =require('../../models')
const Orders = db.orders
const Products = db.products


const orderDetails=async(req,res)=>{

try {
    const order = {
        //user_id: id,
        
        sender_user_id:req.body.sender_user_id,
        order_status:req.body.order_status
     
        
    };

    Orders.findAll({
       where:{
           sender_user_id:req.body.sender_user_id,
           order_status:req.body.order_status

       },
    })
    .then((order) => {
      if (!order) {
        return res.status(400).send({ 
          status:"102", 
          message: "order Not found." });
      }
      else {
        Products.findAll({
         where:{
           product_id:order.product_id
         },
       }).then((product) => {
         if (!product) {
          return res.status(400).send({ 
          status:"102", 
          message: "order Not found." });
        }
        else {
          res.status(200).send({
            status:"VB100",
            orders: order,
            product: product
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
}catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.json({
        status:"102",
        msg: err.message
    })
}

};

module.exports={orderDetails};
```

Update this code as your database fields